# Continue simulation without setting the output port of a LeafSystem

Tags: drake

I have a LeafSystem (using pydrake) with a couple of inputs and an output which is calculated from the inputs. The `CalcOutput` callback function blocks execution of the program until the output is set. In some cases, I prefer to not set the output even if there is an input (eg.out of the limit values).

Is there a way to continue execution, without setting the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drake System's framework uses a "pull" architecture.  All of the system evaluations happen in a single thread, and `CalcOutput` is only called when a downstream method is evaluated which requests an input (e.g. in a downstream `CalcOutput` or `CalcTimeDerivatives`).  So you need to return some value.

I guess that instead of returning some `null` value, you probably want to just have the output port continue to have the value it output last time?  In that case, the solution is to store the output in a state variable (which means moving the work in `CalcOutput` into a state update), and then having your output just write the state variable out to the port.